# Migrate SharePoint 2013 to a farm

Tags: 2013, farm

Our current production environment has a web server and a sql server and our new environment has a hardware load balancer, 2 web servers, an app server and a sql server.

IMHO the install was done incorrectly because they used the production SQL server to setup the farm. Can this be easily fixed by spinning up a new sql server and running through the wizards to point it to the new sql?

The farm is up and running but what is the best practice to get the old databases with all of our sites into the new farm?

Comment: Do u have any data on new farm? Also new farm using the current production sql server?

Comment: No data on new farm. Yes, new farm is using the current production and the installation created some duplicate databases because of this. It is using a new content database so none of the production web sites load up. We plan to spin up a new sql server today and run through the farm setup again and have it use the new db. Do you know which production databases we need to back up and restore to the new farm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you have to run the config wizard and disconnect the server from farms (on new farm). On all new farm servers.

Now run the setup again on new farm and create new config database using the new sql server. After run setup on 2nd server to join it.

As you don't have data on the new farm then you don't need to backup any thing. But if you want to move current production data to new farm then copy all content databases to new farm.

Comment: Ok, thanks, we have gotten that far but after we've imported the production content database to the new sql, we are getting many errors about missing assemblies, missing setup files, site definitions and web parts. Besides the main content database are there other databases that also need to be copied?